# Integrate paytm in mobile app built using ionic1, java

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, paytm

I want to integrate Paytm into the mobile app. I am using ionic1 for this app and server-side language will be java. I have read many articles, blog, even searched on youtube. Couldn't find detailed documentation to integrate paytm.

Code snippets are provided in [paytm documentation](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=example) but I don't know where to place the code and various SDK and file in the project structure.

Can anyone give me the detailed procedure to integrate paytm with the app?

Answer (score 0):

PayTM Integration is one of easily integration I've found so far. They will provide simple class as you mentioned [PayTM](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=how-to-use-apis) In your application where the payment option is available, You need to call their methods. PayTM will provide various keys which you need to add into HashMap.

Example of HashMap would be as below,

```
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
paramMap.put( "MID" , "PAYTM_MERCHANT_ID");
paramMap.put( "ORDER_ID" , "ORDER0000000001");
paramMap.put( "CUST_ID" , "10000988111");
paramMap.put( "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" , "PAYTM_INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID");
paramMap.put( "CHANNEL_ID" , "WAP");
paramMap.put( "TXN_AMOUNT" , "1");
paramMap.put( "WEBSITE" , "PAYTM_WEBSITE");
paramMap.put( "CALLBACK_URL" , "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORDER0000000001");
paramMap.put( "EMAIL" , "abc@gmail.com");
paramMap.put( "MOBILE_NO" , "9999999999");
paramMap.put( "CHECKSUMHASH" , "w2QDRMgp1/BNdEnJEAPCIOmNgQvsi+BhpqijfM9KvFfRiPmGSt3Ddzw+oTaGCLneJwxFFq5mqTMwJXdQE2EzK4px2xruDqKZjHupz9yXev4=")
```

Comment: I have to place [the example code](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=example) in the activity.java file ?? @KulsDroid

Comment: Yeah and call its method where you want to get your payment done